# asp.net page life cycle in refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

This seems to be very primary question, but I met lot of difficulties while implementing my program.

My program Structure is as follows:
[image: Details]

I have 2 content page called News.aspx and Contact.aspx. these two pages contain user controls as well.

I have code for `PreInit` and `Load` in both .aspx page and user control contain `Init` method.

If user is currently in contact.aspx page and then he click on the link button to move to News.aspx page, what is the order of firing those events?

When i put break point and check then it comes in following order.

```
Contact.aspx  PreInit
Contact.aspx Init
News.aspx    PreInit
News.aspx    Init
```

but even though sometimes this works other way around. first  News.aspx methods then abc.aspx page method.

What is the exact order? In addition to that using java script i called web method every page refresh in **onbeforeunload**. in the above scenario that method call as follows:

```
  Contact.aspx  PreInit
    Contact.aspx Init
    Web Method () on Page Refresh
    News.aspx    PreInit
    News.aspx    Init
```

What is the correct order of calling these methods?

Comment: How are you moving someone from Contact.aspx to News.aspx? Response.Redirect?

Comment: First of all the order of calling in not change. Second "do you have some bug ?".

Comment: @vcsjones - yup. I used response.redirect

Comment: @Aristos- i couldn't able to find any bug. what is the correct order of calling these methods?

Comment: If you are on the `Contact.aspx` page, then the `News.aspx` page is not loaded and not firing any events. The only exception to this would be if you are using an `iframe` to display the `News.aspx` page, or you are using some javascript or jQuery magic to dynamically load the page.

Comment: @icemanind I do Not get any exceptions.My problem is What is the correct order of calling above events

Comment: @DevT Why don't you just put a break point in each of the events and see which order they fire?

Comment: @PhilVallone - i put break point & checked. I have mentioned my result above. but i'm confused with my result and i need to confirm whether its correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the order of the life cycle events:

1. News.aspx - Page_PreInit
2. UserControl.ascx - Page_Init
3. MasterPage.master - Page_Init
4. News.aspx - Page_Init
5. News.aspx - Page_Load
6. MasterPage.master - Page_Load
7. UserControl.ascx - Page_Load

The Page's PreInit event is triggered before the controls are initialized, so the user control does not have a PreInit event. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.

Comment: Looks like he is using a master page according to the OP

Comment: i'm not using Tab control. I used link button to navigate each pages. and i'm not adding user controls programmatically... what u mean by not using master page?

Comment: how does this Contact.aspx PreInit call hapens?

Comment: In the situation I listed, the life cycle events of the Contact.aspx page should never be triggered until that page is loaded (e.g. make a request to ~/Contact.aspx). I would have to see your code to tell you more.

Comment: how this `onbeforeunload` effect to this scenario?